I want to add "save & edit" button in Item fulfillment, when click on the button transaction will save and open in edit mode
Add a button "save & edit" in transaction form (item fulfillment) and when click the button then the record will save and open in edit mode. I have tried using event and client script, but it give me an error that rec.save( ) is not a function. Looking into oracle I found out that .save() function didn't work on Client script.
What will be the possible solution for this issue? is there any other way around?
Event script:
/**

@NApiVersion 2.x
@NScriptType ClientScript
*/

    var exports = {};

    function pageInit(context) {
    }
    function onButtonClick() {

        var rec = currentRecord.get();

        rec.save({
            ignoreMandatoryFields: false
        }).then(function(recordId) {
            // After saving, redirect back to edit mode using the record ID
            var baseUrl = url.resolveRecord({
                recordType: rec.type,
                recordId: recordId,
                isEditMode: true
            });

            // Redirect to edit mode of the saved record
            window.location.href = baseUrl;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Error during save:', error.message);
        });
    

    }

    exports.onButtonClick = onButtonClick;
    exports.pageInit = pageInit;
    return exports;
});


/**

@NApiVersion 2.x
@NScriptType UserEventScript
*/


    function beforeLoad(context) {
        var form = context.form;

        if ( context.type === context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
            
            // Add a custom button for "Save and Edit"
            form.addButton({
                id: 'custpage_save_and_edit',
                label: 'Save and Edit',
                functionName: 'onButtonClick'
            });

            // Link the client script for button functionality
            form.clientScriptModulePath = 'SuiteScripts/.js'; // Link to the Client Script
        }
    }

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad
    };
});



I would go with user event after submit entry point and use the N/redirect module to redirect to record

FYI, you can't trigger saving a record from a client script. What you're trying to do will not work, as requested.  This question tells me you're thinking if only your script could do this, then your real problem would be solved. But you should be telling us what your real problem is here, IOW why do you think you need to save and reedit the form in this case?

Agree with Peter, whats the core issue you're trying to solve?
